file_get_contents does not work with ipv6
Within a PHP script I try to read from an IPv6 address by using function file_get_contents but during runtime the following message occur

Failed to open stream: Connection refused

When running the address in browser it returns the message expected.
$return_value = file_get_contents("http://[ipv6-address]");


Connection refused indicates the remote party didn't like your request. "When running the address in browser it returns the message expected." - could be that the site in question is doing a simple check for a User-Agent header like a browser would send, that is one common defense mechanism to block very "basic" bots. file_get_contents uses the configuration value user_agent, which is by default set to NULL. Try and set it to a proper User Agent, and see if you get a different result.

@CBroe It can't check the user agent if it refuses the connection, since the user agent is sent through the connection.

At the end is a simple arduino board that get back just a couple of characters, there is no check. What irritates me a little is that calling the IPv6 address in the browser gives a result and the call via the function is rejected with an error.
